# How to make a basic binding work

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm sure that this (kind of) question is already duplicate so please don't be hard on me ^_^ 
I'm hitting in the dark with this one and having trouble understanding the whole picture, so I'm not sure what to look for.

A Card is a custom immutable class with lots of properties (some of them are other classes too) but to simplify let's say that a Card is this:

```
public class Card
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Power { get; private set; }

    private Card() { }
    public Card(string name, int power)
    {
        Name = name;
        Power = power;
    }
}
```

CardView is a `UserControl` that represents a Card on the UI. It has a Card attached to it.

XAML:

```
<UserControl ... yadayada ...>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">Name: </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Power: </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Power}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class CardView : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CardProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Card", typeof(Card), typeof(CardView));

        private Card _card;
        public CardView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _card = new Card("Chuck", 999);
            this.DataContext = _card;
        }
    }
```

It shows the correct values when created, but I'm missing the last step to allow me to swap the Card at run time.

**Edit:**
In case I didn't explained well, this is what I want to be able to do:

Let's say that I add this method to CardView:

```
public void SetCard(Card card)
{
    _card = card;
}
```

How can I make the bindings update?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: If I change _card to another one, the values on screen doesn't change

Comment: Where and how do you change it? You should change data context or, if you changing dependency property value, then there should be an event rised, something like `this.SendPropertyChanged("Card");`.

Comment: Changing a backing field is not going to affect the UI. And also hard coding a UserControl's DataContext in it's own code behind is a very bad idea. Delete all that and start reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @HighCore, I'd send him straight to learn mvvm ;) But for educational purposes in this specific case correct answer is to set property with [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx), right?

Comment: @Sinatr IMO, the entire DP should be ditched and this should be changed to a `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:Card}">` containing the UserControl instead. Creating a DP just to hold an Element's DataContext is redundant. The `DataContext` property is already there and WPF knows to deal with it already.

Comment: I know that the whole code is very simple, and as stands out it is better using a template. The real XAML is this http://pastebin.com/YYJ2ziQs (the commented parts will be used with a Converter) and is not yet finished, it needs some ValueConverters for some of the fields yet. That is why I've simplified to a class with 2 fields, I though the complexity wasn't needed for the question to be answered

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the `DataContext` as well:

```
public void SetCard(Card card)
{
    _card = card;
    this.DataContext = _card;
}
```